# multiline text component flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-text, flutter-design

I created one reusable multi line text component. I am using TextSpan widget.

code:

```
/// Creates multi line styled widget which displays list of items with bullet
class AppMultiLineText extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<CustomStyledText> items;
  final String semanticsText;

  const AppMultiLineText({@required this.items, this.semanticsText}) : assert(items != null);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final style = context.appThemeData.bodyCopyDefault.appTextStyle;
    final styleBold = context.appThemeData.bodyCopyBold.appTextStyle;
    return MergeSemantics(
      child: Padding(
        padding: context.appThemeData.multilineDisplay.padding,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            _buildRow(context, items, style, styleBold, semanticsText),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _buildRow(BuildContext context, List<CustomStyledText> styledText, AppTextStyle style, AppTextStyle styleBold,
    String semanticsText) {
  final _padding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: context.appThemeData.bulletStyle.spaceBetweenLines);
  return Semantics(
    child: Padding(
      padding: _padding,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          _buildBulletSection(context),
          _styledWidget(context, styledText, style, styleBold, semanticsText),
          
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _buildBulletSection(BuildContext context) {
  // final textScaleFactor = _textScaleFactor(context);
  final _bulletPadding = EdgeInsets.only(
      top: context.appThemeData.bulletStyle.bulletOffset, right: context.appThemeData.bulletStyle.spaceAfterBullet);

  return Text.rich(
    TextSpan(
      children: [
        WidgetSpan(
          child: Padding(
            padding: _bulletPadding,
            child: _drawBullet(context),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    //textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
  );
}

Widget _drawBullet(BuildContext context) {
  final _bulletDiameter = context.appThemeData.bulletStyle.bulletDiameter;
  return Container(
    width: _bulletDiameter,
    height: _bulletDiameter,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: context.appThemeData.bodyCopyDefault.appTextStyle.textStyle.color,
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
    ),
  );
}
Widget _styledWidget(BuildContext context, List<CustomStyledText> styledText, AppTextStyle style,
    AppTextStyle styleBold, String semanticsText) {
  final scaleFactor = context.calculateScaleFactor(
    style.textStyle.fontSize,
    style.maximumFontSize,
    style.minimumScalingFactor,
  );

  return Expanded(
    child: Text.rich(
      TextSpan(
        style: style.textStyle,
        children: styledText.map((e) {
          return TextSpan(
            text: e.text,
            style: e.isBold
                ? styleBold.textStyle.copyWith(
                    letterSpacing: e.isNumeric ? PresentationConstants.numericLetterSpacing : null,
                  )
                : style.textStyle.copyWith(
                    letterSpacing: e.isNumeric ? PresentationConstants.numericLetterSpacing : null,
                  ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
      style: style.textStyle,
      textScaleFactor: scaleFactor,
      textAlign: style.textAlign,
      semanticsLabel: semanticsText,
    ),
  );
}

class CustomStyledText {
  final String text;
  final String styleText;
  final bool isBold;
  final bool isNumeric;

  CustomStyledText(
    this.text, {
    this.styleText,
    this.isBold = false,
    this.isNumeric = false,
  });
}


class:
 AppMultiLineText(
              items: [
                CustomStyledText(context.appLocalization.listOfRequirementsBodyCopy1),
                CustomStyledText(context.appLocalization.listOfRequirementsBodyCopy2),
                
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is the expected design
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZF3w.png

But I am getting all items as paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to use the RichText widget. Details are available [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

May I propose another solution?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> children;

  const CustomList({
    Key key,
    this.children = const [],
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        for (final child in children)
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.circle,
                    size: 4.0,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                Expanded(child: child),
              ],
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Pass any widget you like in to it's children and it will append the dots automatically:

```dart
CustomList(
            children: [
              Text('My first line of text'),
              Text(
                'My second line of text which is long enough, long enough,  long enough,  long enough,  long enough,  long enough',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

----------- Addon -----------

You can go even further and add a "type" to switch from unordered to ordered style.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum CustomListType { Unordered, Ordered }

class CustomList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> children;
  final CustomListType type;

  const CustomList({
    Key key,
    this.children = const [],
    this.type = CustomListType.Unordered,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _children = <Widget>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      _children.add(Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            type == CustomListType.Ordered
                ? Text('${i + 1}.')
                : Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.circle,
                      size: 4.0,
                    ),
                  ),
            SizedBox(width: 10.0),
            Expanded(child: children.elementAt(i)),
          ],
        ),
      ));
    }
    return Column(
      children: _children,
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
CustomList(
            type: CustomListType.Ordered,
            children: [
              Text('My first line of text'),
              Text(
                'My second line of text which is long enough, long enough,  long enough,  long enough,  long enough,  long enough',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```